# Вызов части кода в функции Python

Tags: python

Здраствуйте. Есть несколько переменных в функции.

```
def get_item():
    
    r = requests.get(ulr, headers=headers)  # Меняется только URL
    get_request_offer = json.loads(r.text)['Offers'] # Переменная 1
    get_request_target = json.loads(r.text)['Targets'] # Переменная 2
    offers = get_request_offer[0], get_request_offer[1], get_request_offer[2], get_request_offer[3], get_request_offer[4] # Переменная 3
    targets = get_request_target[0], get_request_ target[1], get_request_target[2], get_request_target[3], get_request_target[4] # Переменная 4
```

Условно говоря эта функция посылает запрос и получает JSON ответ который я перебираю и заношу в excel. Это запрос только для одного предмета (`url` запрос), а у меня их 200+. Возникает вопрос. Чтоб каждый раз этот кусок кода не повторять, а повторять только запрос с изменённым 'url', вставлять под переменную `r`. Либо вызовом из другого файла, либо занести 4 переменные в "переменную" и сделать вызов под следующим. Пример:

```
r requests.get(url2, ...)
global_request
```

Где global_request является 4-мя переменными описанными ранее.

Comment: Вам нужно передавать переменную `url` в функцию `get_item()`. То есть, `def get_item(url)`. затем просто идете по списку адресов и передаете их в функцию.

Comment: И вообще,  вас заголовок вопроса, очевидно, не имеет никакого отношения к его содержимому...

Comment: ```def get_item(url) -> list:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)  # Меняется только URL
    get_request = None
    if r.json['Offers']:
        get_request = r.json["Offers"]
    elif r.json['Targets']:
        get_request = r.json["Targets"]
    return get_request[0:5]```

Comment: Прошу прощения. Я новичок и это мой второй вопрос на сайте. Возвращаясь к вашему ответу. Мои запросы ведут на уникальный url. По этому каждая ссылка имеет переменную. Т.е ulr1, ulr2, ulr3...ulr200. И вопрос состоял в том, что можно ли вынести переменные с функции, дать им "переменную" и вызывать в любой части текста.

Comment: У Ваших уникальных ссылок всегда возвращается ответ к котором есть или "Offers" или "Targets"? Если да, тогда лучше создать словарь, в котором будет ключ  это ваша уникальная сслыка, значение ответ возвращаемое значение с функции